# I want to pass touch event for a transparent custom cell to its parent view (which is a pageview controller)?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview

I'm trying for this solution from many days, I have a scenario where I want to pass touch even (Swiping for page view controller) of my first custom cell to the parent view which is a page view controller. 
Here my first cell in the table view is a transparent cell. It is not visible instead of we can see the background view which is a super class of table view controller and it is a page view controller. So here I want to pass the touch event which should be swiping for page view controller. And all the remaining cells are not transparent. Here I'm sending the image so that you can understand. easily. So help me out in passing the swipe/touch to my page view controller [Basic Look with transparent cell  on top](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TDSyX.png) So in that transparent cell area we can see the super view of table view controller which is a page view controller.[image: requirement]
As you can see left side is the basic look, and in that you can see the page view controller, and then the right side image is when we scroll the cells it will look like this.
So now you can understand clearly the height of table view and my requirement too.
So how to pass touch/ swipe event to the page view controller when we select transparent cell(indexpath.row ==0 first cell)
I tried the solution that given but no use..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add one more view on top of it (pageview -> cellview -> new view on top with opacity = 0). Next add swipe gesture to new view and finally make a newView.delegate = pageviewController to capture swipe event.

```
@protocol NewViewControllerDelegate<NSObject>
-(void)gestureDidFire;
@end
@interface NewViewController : UIViewController
// you gesture outlet look like IBAction *swipeGestureReconizer;
@property (nonatomic, assign)id <NewViewControllerDelegate>delegate;
@end

//newViewContrlloer.m
- IBAction swipeGestureReconizer
{
    if(self.delegate && [self.delegate responseToSelector:@seletor(gestureDidFire)])
    {
        [self.delegate gestureDidFire];
    }
}

//in your page view interface

@interface yourPageView()<NewViewControllerDelegate>
{
    //need  instance of newView
    newViewController.delegate = self;
}
-(void)gestureDidFire
{
    //implement what you want
}
```

Comment: I'm really thankful to you for the answer. And its working fine. But I didnt get how to write this newView.delegate = pageviewController ? I think I have to write in this method..       -(void)swipeHandler:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer *)recognizer {
    NSLog(@"Swipe received.");
} Inside this how to pass the delegate

Comment: Actually I'm not good at delegation, But what i understood is I have to create a delegate property in page view controller and i need to import that into custom cell and i have to call it here as you said "newView.delegate = pageviewController" and in this do i have to create any methods and I'm I going properly or not ? please let me know

Comment: Delegate is the most common pattern use in Cocoa and CoacoaTouch, you have to learn and master it, the best way is making some small tutorial to understand how it works first.

Comment: I tried this but its not working, I'm really confused how to do this